# Unique ID for network clusters

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, networkx

I have a network of nodes (parends/childs, each with an id) and want to generate a unique ID for each cluster of connected nodes. I'm using Python, Pandas and networkx.

For example, I have

```
id  a    b    c
1  101  201  301
2  101  202  302
3  102  202  302
4  103  203  303
5  103  204  304
```

where, for instance, in column `a`, lines 1 and 2 are linked.

I'd like to obtain

```
id  a    b    c   id_cluster
1  101  201  301      1
2  101  202  302      1
3  102  202  302      1
4  103  203  303      2
5  103  204  304      2
```

Comment: Why is id 3 in  id_cluster 1?

Comment: Because line 1 is connected to line 2 in column a, and lines 2 and 3 are connected in columns b and c.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, if I'm understanding things correctly, this is equivalent to having two types of nodes:

1. Nodes in your DataFrame, which have and `id`
2. Combination of column and value in your DataFrame

and this DataFrame are the edges of the graph.

So, `(a, 101)` connects to `1` & `2`

and `(b, 202)` connects to `2` & `3`

So, all of `1`, `2`, `3`, `(a, 101)`, `(a, 102)`, `(b, 201)`, `(b, 202)`, `(c, 301)`, and `(c, 302)` are connected.

I'm not familiar with `networkx`, but it seems like there is a function called `connected_components` which gives you connected subgraphs.  So,

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
from StringIO import StringIO


df = pd.read_table(StringIO("""
id  a    b    c
1  101  201  301
2  101  202  302
3  102  202  302
4  103  203  303
5  103  204  304"""), delim_whitespace=True)

df = df.set_index('id')

G = nx.Graph()
for (id_, column), other_node in df.stack().iteritems():
    G.add_edge(id_, (column, other_node))

cluster_map = pd.Series(
    {id_: id_cluster + 1
     for id_cluster, ids in enumerate(nx.connected_components(G))
     for id_ in ids
     if not isinstance(id_, tuple)},
    name='id_cluster')

df = df.join(cluster_map)
print(df)
```

yields

```
      a    b    c  id_cluster
id                           
1   101  201  301           1
2   101  202  302           1
3   102  202  302           1
4   103  203  303           2
5   103  204  304           2
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked nicely and more concisely that my previous solution.